# Django/Python Getting "error_message" : "multiple repeats" on using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, django

I am trying to add a more efficient swear filter to a chat service we have and can't seem to get my regular expression working on my live django server.

I am running the latest stable Django on Python 2.6.7.

Here is my code:

```
def replacement(match):
    return "*" * len(match.group(0))

def censored_string(cFilter, dirty):
    clean = str(dirty)
    wordList = cFilter.mutations.split(',')
    wordList.sort(key = len)
    wordList.reverse()

    for swear_word in wordList:
        target_word = swear_word.strip()
        result = re.sub("(?i)\\b(("+target_word+"){1,})(s{0,1})\\b",replacement, clean)
        clean = result
    return clean
```

for the record - this works using my local server setup which I can confirm is also using python 2.6.7 and the same django version, however I have not done much django or python since about 10 months ago and inherited this server setup recently - if there is something I am missing please let me know.

the output of the error is as follows:

```
{
    "error_message": "multiple repeat",
    "traceback": ... "result = re.sub(\"(?i)\\\\b(\"+target_word+\"){1,}(s{0,1})\\\\b\",censored_word(target_word), clean)\n\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.6/re.py\", line 151, in sub\n    return _compile(pattern, 0).sub(repl, string, count)\n\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.6/re.py\", line 245, in _compile\n    raise error, v # invalid expression\n\nerror: multiple repeat\n"
}
```

I have tried with and without greedy's and so forth but am lost now - any input would be greatly appreciated

cheers,

Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the problem is with the regex, but with your word list. It's likely the list contains characters which are interpreted as regex special characters. This works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re

def replacement(match):
    return "*" * len(match.group(0))

def censored_string(dirty):
    clean = str(dirty)
    wordList = ["fuck", "shit", "damn"]

    for swear_word in wordList:
        target_word = swear_word.strip()
        result = re.sub("(?i)\\b(("+target_word+"){1,})(s{0,1})\\b",replacement, clean)
        clean = result
    return clean

print censored_string("god damn i love bananas and fucking fuckfuck shits")
# god **** i love bananas and fucking ******** *****
```

Comment: brilliant - I just tried with a hard-coded list and it worked. thank you so very very much :)

Comment: Shouldn't that really be `god **** i love bananas and ****ing ******** *****`?

Comment: You could be of that opinion, but that's not what the regex says. OP can post another question for help with that ;)

Answer (score 1):

That "multiple repeat" error from `re` literally means that there are more than one repetition directives applied to the same expression in your pattern.

The repetition directives can be `*`, `+`, `?`, `{m}`, `{m,n}`, etc. If more than one of these are applied to a pattern, you will get that error. Again, it's most likely that `target_word` contains regex special characters that you probably forgot to escape. Use `re.escape()` to do exactly that and give it another shot.

I.E.

```
result = re.sub("(?i)\\b((" + re.escape(target_word) + "){1,})(s{0,1})\\b", replacement, clean)
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone kindly upvote the answer above from Devy .

My own usecase is also with "re" and "Django" .

Got the Error -- "multiple repeat at position 12"
my initial code as below --

```
str_7 = re.findall(r'([\d+]{1,20}[A-Z])',str_7)
## multiple repeat at position 12#
```

Error above ---> (r'([\d+]{1,20} -- Cant have "\d+" AND {1,20} , both together.

Also `re.escape` as suggested elsewhere is not the ideal solution - try not to have more than one - "repetition directive"

Thus as in my case - the " Plus Operator" or "Positive Closure" , should not be followed by the "Brace Operator" {m,n}